# If I need polymorphism should I use raw pointers instead of unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, polymorphism, smart-pointers

If I need polymorphism should I use raw pointers instead of `unique_ptr` ?

I saw some threads that show how to use `unique_ptr` for polymorphic behaviour.
I am not sure it is worth the trouble, I would rather stay with raw pointers.
Can you please comment on this, your opinion on raw vs smart pointers in this context?

Comment: Don't use non-private raw pointers. They're impossible to use correctly, essentially.

Comment: That is a good point. In my case I can keep them private.

Comment: Can you point to the threads. AFAIK there is no difference between raw pointer or `unique_pointer` or `shared_pointer` wrt polymorphism. They all work the same way.

Comment: "I am not sure it is worth the trouble" -> Not sure what you mean, raw pointers are way more trouble than smart pointers.

Answer (score 23):

The following simple code shows that `std::unique_ptr` works just fine from a polymorphism point of view, printing `"Hello from Derived."`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using std::cout;

struct Base 
{
    virtual ~Base() { }

    virtual void SayHello()
    {
        cout << "Hello from Base.\n";
    }
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    void SayHello() override
    {
        cout << "Hello from Derived.\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> pBase( new Derived() );
    
    // Or using std::make_unique:
    //
    // std::unique_ptr<Base> pBase = std::make_unique<Derived>();      
    
    pBase->SayHello();
}
```

Anyway, **observing** raw pointers are fine; what you must pay attention to are **owning** raw pointers. Owning raw pointers should be safely wrapped inside RAII boundaries (using `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, or some custom resource manager).

Comment: make_unique would have been better here.

Comment: @avernus: I added a comment showing the `make_unique` syntax, but I think that is not particularly important in this case.

Comment: If you're getting a compile error, you may want to check that you didn't forget the **public Base** part.

Answer (score 3):

- Use `unique_ptr` to control ownership of allocated resources, e.g. allocate on the free store inside a function and return a `unique_ptr`.
- Use just a reference for polymorphic behavior if ownership is not an issue. Even if a `unique_ptr` does the same, you spare the compiler from additional work.
- Use a pointer for polymorphic behavior within a container if ownership is not an issue. You cannot have a container of references.

Answer (score 2):

Smart pointers are about ownership/lifetime.  Where you need to manage the lifetime of a polymorphic object, use a smart pointer.  If you are just using the object, prefer raw references/pointers (in that order) over smart pointers.